# JQ: perform token replacement

Tags: json, jq, template-engine

I'd like to replace the tokens in `text` with the variables defined in `ma`. Input JSON:

```
{
    "ma":{
        "a":"1",
        "b":"2",
        "c":"3"
    },
    "mb":{
        "a":"11"
    },
    "text":"https://ph.com?a={a}&b={b}"
}
```

Desired result: `https://ph.com?a=1&b=2`

Extra credit, how can I have `mb` variables take precedence over `ma` variables so that my resulting text is: `https://ph.com?a=11&b=2` ?

I've tried using combinations of `scan` and `sub` and `walk` but can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a function to replace the tokens with the new values.

```
def format($map): gsub("\\{(?<key>[^}]+)\\}"; "\($map[.key])");
```

With this, you can then pass in the map for the replacements.

```
.ma as $map | .text | format($map)
```

Update the mapping as needed.

```
(.ma * .mb) as $map | .text | format($map)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're stuck with the `{a}`-style template names, then see @JeffMercado's answer; if, however, you have control over the templating style, it would make things much simpler if you used jq's string-interpolation feature.

For example, if the template string (.text) were `"https://ph.com?a=\\(.a)&b=\\(.b)"` then if you just want the value of `.text` after substitution, you could simply write:

```
(.ma + .mb) as $map | .text | $map
```

Or if you wanted in-place substitution:

```
(.ma + .mb) as $map
| .text |= $map
```